# How to write Fibonacci with generator without stop number

Tags: python, fibonacci

I went through [Beginning Python fibonacci generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838152/beginning-python-fibonacci-generator)

How to write with out stop number where we want to stop.

My Code of FIbnocci is below

```
def Fibonnaci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (Fibonnaci(n-1)+ Fibonnaci(n-2))

n = int(input())
print(Fibonnaci(n))
```

I wrote with yield statement but its infinite loop running

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

fib(7)
```

Desired out >
    13

Comment: Just add a counter to `fib(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to loop infinitely; you need to keep track of how many times you've performed an operation.

Hold the state of a counter in your loop while you generate elements.  Keep going until `count >= n`.

```
def fib(n):
     count = 0
     a, b = 0, 1
     while count < n:
             yield a
             a, b = b, a + b
             count += 1
```

You can then leverage this in a list comprehension to get all of the values up to that Fibonacci number if you so desire.

```
[i for i in fib(10)]
```

Comment: You can also use `for _ in range(n):` getting rid of the `count` var. `list(fib(10))` from the caller is an alternative to the list comp.

Comment: @ggorlen:  This is more meant to be illustrative of the kind of state that needs to be held.  I'm sure this could be done in a different way but I don't think that the way you're describing it would make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `yield` statement is used to **iterate** over some data, yielding one value at a time.

So: **iterate** over it

```
f = fib()
fibs = [next(f) for _ in range(7)]
fib_7 = fibs[-1]
```

**note** as you start with `yield a` you get a 0 as first number. so shift to `yield b` which will work as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b  #swap the values, sum

def firstn(g, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield g.__next__() # take  the next value for the generator


t =  (list(firstn(fibonacci(), n+1))) # Put in a list
print (t[-1])   #take the last element
```

Comment: Care to explain all of this?